# Selecting row(s) imperatively

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

Is there any way to set a row or multiple rows as checked imperatively in [mui-datatables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-datatables)?

In the documentation the only thing I found even close was a `setSelectedRows` function passed to `customToolbarSelect`, but you can only access this function as a trigger after a row has already been manually selected.

I want the ability to write a function outside the datatable component that can change the "checked" state of a row. Particularly the ability to set all rows on a page as checked without setting every row in every page as checked. The built in "select all" functionality only performs the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is passing a state object to the rowsSelected prop like this:

```js
// selected rows is an array of indices
const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = React.useState([3]);

const options: MUIDataTableOptions = {
...
rowsSelected: selectedRows, // on init, the 4th row will be checked
...
}

return (
<>
  <Button onClick={() => setSelectedRows([1, 2, 3])}>Change!</Button>
  <MUIDataTable ... options={options} />
</>
)
```

Clicking on the `Change!` button will set the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th, rows to checked and uncheck all the others.